# Javascript getDate() function returning one day ahead in Lambda function

Tags: javascript, date, lambda

I am currently in Central time, and it is 7:19pm on 2/6/2018

I have this line of Javascript in my code:

```
var d = new Date();
var theMonth = d.getMonth() + 1;
var theDay = d.getDate();
var theYear = d.getFullYear();

var formattedStartDate = theYear + "-" + theMonth + "-" + theDay;
console.log(formattedStartDate);
```

The problem is, that this actually prints

```
2018-2-7
```

I am running hosting this code through AWS Lambda in the US East endpoint, so I cannot see why it would be using the wrong date completely. What could be the issue?

Comment: Where is the code running, on the server or your locality? If the server, the system is likely set to UTC, so you are seeing the UTC date, not your local date (your time is 21:19 Central, which is 3:19 the next day UTC).

Comment: I'm not sure how AWS Lambda works. I am guessing it is running through N. Virginia, where it says it is being hosted. How can I change this to my local date?

Comment: I have no idea, but where a system is located isn't necessarily reflected in its timezone offset, especially for servers.

Comment: instead of logging formatted date, log variable `d` and you will see what date (and TZ) in on your server. After that just make correction to your zone. but I would advise you to use UTC and just convert to user date when  its needed.

Answer (score 0):

Moment.js can handle this for you.  https://momentjs.com/

`moment(d).utcOffset('-0600')` will set the timezone to Central.  The code below has two console.log statements at the end.  The first one prints date/time before setting the timezone and the second prints date/time after setting timezone to show you that it works.  I've included time on the date object so you can see the correct timezone has been applied during any time of the day.

As an added bonus, moment.js will also simplify the formatting of your dates.

```js
'use strict';

var moment = require('moment');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    
var d = new Date();
var theMonth = d.getMonth() + 1;
var theDay = d.getDate();
var theYear = d.getFullYear();

var formattedStartDate = theYear + "-" + theMonth + "-" + theDay;
console.log(formattedStartDate);

console.log(d);  //prints current datetime before applying timezone
d = moment(d).utcOffset('-0600').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'); //applies Central timezone
console.log(d);  //prints updated timezone


};
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda sets its local time to UTC so `getDate()` and `getUTCDate()` will have the same result.